# dynamically adding smaller Views on a large zoomable ImageView?

Tags: android, android-layout

i have a large zooming, panning ImageView containing an image as it's bitmap. i want to add many smaller Views on top of it at the point where the user performs a LongClick action on it. these Views have to be positioned at the fixed location and must stay glued to that location when the user zooms or moves around the large ImageView below it. How should i go about this?

(i'm trying to get the same functionality as the ItemizedOverlay class does while adding markers on Google Maps, but on an ImageView instead.)

Comment: did you got any answer?